# Passing an array of condition to query where method in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

How can I pass two conditions to the method of `query` which is `where`? I tried using `$query->where($cond[0])`, it worked but on `$query->where($cond[1])` it gives an error of undefined offset.

```
public function search($params, $cond)
{
    $query = ServiceStatuses::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => ['defaultOrder' => ['last_hard_state' => SORT_DESC]],
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    .
    .
    .

    $query->where($cond[0]);      //<<<<----- This works
    $query->where($cond[1]);      //<<<<----- Undefined offset: 1

    return $dataProvider;
}

public function searchIncidents($params)
{
    $cond = array (['last_hard_state' => 0, 'last_hard_state' => 2]);
    $dataProvider = $this->search($params, $cond);
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$cond` variable is creating an array within an array; you're using both `array()` and shorthand syntax `[]` (added in PHP 5.4). If you only intend `$cond` to be a single level array, remove one of the array calls. Either

`$cond = ['last_hard_state' => 0, 'last_hard_state' => 2];`

or

`$cond = array('last_hard_state' => 0, 'last_hard_state' => 2);`

Comment: Hi! thanks, this fixed the undefined offset but I noticed that the last condition is only evaluated. How can I query both conditions?

Comment: Try changing `$query->where($cond[0]);` to `$query->where($cond);`  and remove the second `where` call. since you want to query both. `$cond[0]` or `$cond[1]` will only pick one of those out of the array.

Comment: I tried using `$query->where($cond);` but it only evaluates the last part, which is on your example is `'last_hard_state' => 2` only

Comment: Oh duh, I didnt even see that the keys in the array were the same. The second key is overwriting the first since they're the same, which is only evaluating the last one.

Can you tell me what the where clause is supposed to do? `WHERE last_hard_state = 0 OR last_hard_state = 2` maybe?

Comment: yes that's it, well it actually works if i just placed them in a string like this `'last_hard_state = 2 || last_hard_state = 0'` but if there's another way in array I'd like also to learn since I read that it also accepts array on the documentation

Comment: Sure, I'm looking at https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-query-builder.md#operator-format-

Looks like you can change the array to something like
`['or', 'last_hard_state=0', 'last_hard_state=2']`

and that should generate `last_hard_state = 0 OR last_hard_state = 2`